# ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which have three columns which are

Table name is `BFILETABEL`

```
FILEID (number) //number data type
FILENAME (varchar2)
FILEDATA (BFILE) //Data type is BFILE
```

In my C# code i am trying to create a directory and then insert it in a table row

```
private void bFileInsertFileInOracle(string fileName)
        {
        string[] getFileNameFromAddress = fileName.Split('\\');

        myConnection.Open();
        OracleCommand createFolder = new OracleCommand();
        createFolder.Connection = myConnection;

        createFolder.CommandText = "CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY bfileimages AS 'C:\\TEMP\\bfileimages'";
        createFolder.ExecuteNonQuery();

        String strSQL = "INSERT INTO BFILETABEL VALUES (" + bFileFileIDS + ",'" + fileName + "', BFILENAME('BFILEIMAGES', '" + getFileNameFromAddress[getFileNameFromAddress.Length - 1] + "'))";

        OracleCommand cm = new OracleCommand();
        cm.Connection = myConnection;
        cm.CommandText = strSQL;
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnection.Close();
        }
```

In that "fileName" is a path to image file. No exception is shown when it is executed. I mean no exception show like user privileges exception, nothing is shown. But when i select that file and open it exception is generated which is

```
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Code for that function is

```
        private void bFileShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        int getNumber = Convert.ToInt16(BFileTextboxImgID.Text);

        myConnection.Open();
        OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand("select * from BFILETABEL where fileid=" + getNumber + "", myConnection);
        ocmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = 2;
        OracleDataReader rd = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
        rd.Read();
        OracleBFile getBlob = rd.GetOracleBFile(2);
        getBlob.OpenFile();   // exception occurs at that line 
        if (getBlob.FileExists)
            {
            label1.Text = getBlob.FileName.ToString(); 
            getBlob.OpenFile();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

            getBlob.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            getBlob.Read(buffer, 0, 100);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            blobPictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
        myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Does the folder C:\TEMP\bfileimages\ exist on your database server?

Comment: That folder doesn't exists but i tried C:\TEMP, that folder exists but still i get that error

Comment: What about the image, is the image in the folder C:\TEMP - on the DB server, not on your client PC? Has Oracle read/write privilege to access that folder?

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your code that the file is already located on the c:\temp directory. So you are only associating the existing file in c:\temp with a bfile pointer on Oracle. If you don't have the file already in the target folder, use code such as listed below in a stored procedure to insert from C#. This code is taken from the document management system of Invantive Vision we have developed but feel free to use this part of our code in any way you like. After uploading it, you will need to insert the pointer in your bfile table.

Further check also that you are using ODP.Net and some recent version. It fixes a lot of common problems.

Also always code the column list in the insert statement. When Oracle gets a wild day and your columns are reordered, the insert will magically fail or have funny effects:

```
String strSQL = "INSERT INTO BFILETABEL VALUES (" + bFileFileIDS + ",'" + fileName + "', BFILENAME('BFILEIMAGES', '" + getFileNameFromAddress[getFileNameFromAddress.Length - 1] + "'))";
```

becomes

> String strSQL = "INSERT INTO BFILETABEL **(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3,
>   COLUMN4)** VALUES (" + bFileFileIDS + ",'" + fileName + "',
>   BFILENAME('BFILEIMAGES', '" +
>   getFileNameFromAddress[getFileNameFromAddress.Length - 1] + "'))";

It is a good recommendation to also replace the insert statement by something with parameters (faster when repeatedly executed) or properly escape the values. Maybe someone uses a file name with a quote in it which will lead to an error on parsing the SQL.

Sample uploading a blob in a directory:

```
procedure write_blob_to_file
( p_directory varchar2
, p_filename  varchar2
, p_blob      blob
)
as
  l_fh                       utl_file.file_type;
  l_blob_length              integer;
  l_buffer                   raw(32767);
  l_chunk_size               binary_integer := 32767;
  l_blob_position            integer := 1;
begin
  l_blob_length := dbms_lob.getlength(p_blob);
  l_fh := utl_file.fopen(p_directory, p_filename, 'wb', l_chunk_size);
  --
  -- Write the BLOB to file in chunks
  --
  while l_blob_position <= l_blob_length
  loop
    if l_blob_position + l_chunk_size - 1 > l_blob_length
    then
      l_chunk_size := l_blob_length - l_blob_position + 1;
    end if;
    dbms_lob.read(p_blob, l_chunk_size, l_blob_position, l_buffer);
    utl_file.put_raw(l_fh, l_buffer, true);
    l_blob_position := l_blob_position + l_chunk_size;
  end loop;
  utl_file.fclose(l_fh);
exception
  when others
  then
    --
    -- Close file if necessary.
    -- Ignore any errors.
    --
    begin
      if utl_file.is_open(l_fh)
      then
        utl_file.fclose(l_fh);
      end if;
    exception
      when others
      then
        null;
    end;
    --
    rollback;
    itgen_error_handler.add_to_inner_stack;
    raise;
end;
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It works i place file in C:\TEMP . I mean, for example if user wants to upload "blue hills.jpg". I copy file in that C:\TEMP and then i execute queries which are like

```
CREATE or REPLACE DIRECTORY directoryName as 'C:\TEMP'
```

Insert query is

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUEs ('1',BFILENAME('DIRECTORYNAME','blue hills.jpg'))
```